# When does hoisting apply?

Tags: javascript

I use this pattern for some of my code:

```
(function () {
    var a,
        b,
        c,
        d;

    a = // some module definition
    b = // some module definition
    c = // some module definition
    d = // some module definition

}());
```

What I've noticed is that if `b` needs access to `a` it must be defined before it.  So `b` can reference `a`, but `a` can not reference `b`.

I found this strange because I thought a process called hoisting allowed me to not have to define my modules in any particular order.

But what I'm finding is that ordering does matter.

Comment: Not sure but I think when you declare without assignment you are only specifying the scope of the variable but it is still undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the `var`  declaration is hoisted. Not the `=` assignment.

This means you can refer to a variable whose `var` declaration comes later in the function without getting a *ReferenceError*, but its value will be `undefined` until the assignment actually takes place.

```
(function() {

    alert(b);  // undefined
    var b = "foo";
    alert(b);  // "foo"
})();
```

Because of the "hoisting", the above example effectively turns into this:

```
(function() {
    var b;
    alert(b);  // undefined
    b = "foo";
    alert(b);  // "foo"
})();
```

Comment: ...hoisting seems kind of point-less...you have access to the variable sooner but it is undefined.

Comment: @pure_code: Agreed. I think it was made part of the language to avoid ReferenceErrors when someone tries to access a variable too soon. Unfortunately, the ReferenceError proves to be more useful as an indicator that something is wrong compared to just getting `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Hoisting means the declaration happens earlier but the assignment doesn't move. The variable will be declared but will be undefined.

Hoisting can cause confusion due to scoping issues. So for instance:

```
var a = 1;
var somFunc = function(){
  var b = a;
  alert(b); // alert undefined
  var a = 3
}
someFunc();
```

The alert in this case is 'undefined' as the second `var a` is `hoisted` above the `var b`, but the assignment is left till after, and the first `a` assignment is overwritten because it is outside the scope.